# Copy all files command not working in command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

I am trying to copy all files in RegBack folder (C:/Windows/System32/config/RegBack) to the config folder. When I type `copy *.* ..`, it says:

```
*.*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

Please help!

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to copy files into another Windows protected directory, unless you are running your cmd.exe, _(Command Prompt)_, session elevated. Try openinig cmd.exe using the 'Run as administrator' option, then use `Copy /Y "C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\*" "C:\Windows\System32\config"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that the folder does not contain any files.
Try to type DIR to ensure this folder is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Open windows CMD with administrator after that navigate to the path C:/Windows/System32/config

Use the below command that might help

**Xcopy /E /I RegBack config**

This will actually copy all the files from source to destination